# how to merge collections into a specific column in laravel

Tags: laravel, collections

I have 3 collections of different objects. I need to aggregate these 3 collections into 1 according to the shared value (here shared value is `id`).
I mean:

```
$names = {"id":1, "name":"John"};
$ages = {"id":1, "age":20};
$address = "{"id":1, "address":"222"};
  .......
 .........
```

if I return `return $names->merge($ages)->merge($address)`, it will show me like this:

```
[
  {"id":1, "name":"John"},
  {"id":1, "age":20},
  {"id":1, "address":"222"},
  {"id":2, "name":"Jim"},
  {"id":2, "age":30},
  {"id":2, "address":"333"},
]
```

I want to return me like this:

```
[
   {"id":1, "name":"John", "age":20 , "address":"222"},
   {"id":2, "name":"Jim", "age":30 , "address":"333"}
 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
$items = [
  {"id":1, "name":"John"},
  {"id":1, "age":20},
  {"id":1, "address":"222"},
  {"id":2, "name":"Jim"},
  {"id":2, "age":30},
  {"id":2, "address":"333"},
];

$items = collect($items)->groupBy('id');
$result = [];
foreach ($items as $values) {
  $temp = [];
  foreach ($values as $value) {
    $temp = array_merge($temp, $value);
  }
  $result[] = $temp;
}

dd($result);
```